# How to solve circular dependency between three header files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, circular-dependency

Please note: this kind of question has been asked on SO, but I believe mine is different, since the solution alone of using partial `struct X*` types doesn't solve this. I have read the other answers and have found no solution, so please bear with me.

I have the following circular-dependency problem (resulting in a compile error) which I'm unable to solve.

`value.h` relies on `chunk.h`, which relies on `value_array.h`, which relies on `value.h`.

Originally - `chunk.h` used to rely directly on `value.h` as well. I have managed to eliminate that dependency by having `addConstant` take a `struct Value*` instead of `Value`.

But I still haven't figured out how I can remove the dependency between `value_array.h` and `value.h`. The problem is that functions in `value_array.c` need to know the `sizeof(Value)`, and so their signature can't take the partial type `struct Value*`.

Suggestions would be welcome.

The slightly simplified code:

**value.h**

```
#ifndef plane_value_h
#define plane_value_h

#include "chunk.h"

typedef enum {
    VALUE_NUMBER,
    VALUE_BOOLEAN,
    VALUE_CHUNK
} ValueType;

typedef struct Value {
    ValueType type;
    union {
        double number;
        bool boolean;
        Chunk chunk;
    } as;
} Value;

#endif
```

**chunk.h**

```
#ifndef plane_chunk_h
#define plane_chunk_h

#include "value_array.h"

typedef struct {
    uint8_t* code;
    ValueArray constants;
    int capacity;
    int count;
} Chunk;

void initChunk(Chunk* chunk);
void writeChunk(Chunk* chunk, uint8_t byte);
void setChunk(Chunk* chunk, int position, uint8_t byte);
void freeChunk(Chunk* chunk);
int addConstant(Chunk* chunk, struct Value* constant);

#endif
```

**value_array.h**

```
#ifndef plane_value_array_h
#define plane_value_array_h

#include "value.h"

typedef struct {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    Value* values;
} ValueArray;

void value_array_init(ValueArray* array);

void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, Value value);

void value_array_free(ValueArray* array);

#endif
```

**value_array.c**

```
#include "value_array.h"

void value_array_init(ValueArray* array) {
    array->values = NULL;
    array->count = 0;
    array->capacity = 0;
}

void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, Value value) {
    if (array->count == array->capacity) {
        int oldCapacity = array->capacity;
        array->capacity = GROW_CAPACITY(oldCapacity);
        array->values = reallocate(array->values, sizeof(Value) * oldCapacity, sizeof(Value) * array->capacity, "Dynamic array buffer");
    }

    array->values[array->count++] = value;
}

void value_array_free(ValueArray* array) {
    deallocate(array->values, array->capacity * sizeof(Value), "Dynamic array buffer");
    value_array_init(array);
}
```

Comment: If Chunk.c doesn't explicitly need to know type of Value, you could leave it as a void* and access its members directly through offsets. But someone stated move `void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, Value value);` to another file and that's probably your best bet

Comment: Do not get hung up on the specific organization of your declarations into various headers -- although splitting things up in such a way is useful, your issue does not revolve around that.  *Do* appreciate that structure types can be forward-declared, provided that you give them tags.  The full definition of such a type does not need to be known for declaration of pointers to that type or for using that type in function prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

ValueArray does not have to know what a value is because it contains only a pointer, which is opaque. Do not include Value.h from ValueArray.h

One question is why you are doing this when there are template classes like vector in C++ that will do this for you, but if you are determined to write your own list in C, then

```
#pragma once
struct Value;

typedef struct {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    struct Value* values;
} ValueArray;

void value_array_init(ValueArray* array);
void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, const Value* value);
void value_array_free(ValueArray* array);




#include "value_array.h"
#include "value.h"

void value_array_init(ValueArray* array) {
    array->values = NULL;
    array->count = 0;
    array->capacity = 0;
}

void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, const Value* value) {
    if (array->count == array->capacity) {
        int oldCapacity = array->capacity;
        array->capacity = GROW_CAPACITY(oldCapacity);
        array->values = reallocate(array->values, sizeof(Value) * oldCapacity, sizeof(Value) * array->capacity, "Dynamic array buffer");
    }

    array->values[array->count++] = value;
}

void value_array_free(ValueArray* array) {
    deallocate(array->values, array->capacity * sizeof(Value), "Dynamic array buffer");
    value_array_init(array);
}
```

In other words, you only think this isn't a duplicate of the other questions, the answer is, of course it is. The only other possibility was that you had a recursive definition in which one object included the others, in which case your code would be impossible.

You do not want to write a function passing Value by value. No, it won't work given your circular definition, and also it's slow. Why would you want to copy a large object on the stack? Pass it by reference.

Comment: Hi Dov, please see my edit adding the implementation of `value_array.c`. In it you can see I have to use `sizeof(Value)`, which complicates things. Hence this question. :)

Comment: Just pointing out that writing your own list data structure is not a great idea

Comment: The implementation can include Value.h, that is not circular

Comment: @Dov, yeah, but the signature for `value_array_write` must specify `Value`, because its signature has to match the one in the implementation file. Am I wrong?

Comment: I said to use a pointer, not by value, that solves one problem. Then include the definition value.h that solves the other problem

Comment: I just added the include to the source file in my answer since you don't seem to understand

Comment: You're quite right, @Dov, that the question is a dupe.  That being the case, however,  the appropriate action would be to VTC as a dupe.  Nevertheless, this answer is mostly right, though it does overlook the fact that it is not necessary to convert the structure parameter in the function prototype to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, Value value);
```

to this:

```
void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, const Value* value);
```

or move this:

```
void value_array_write(ValueArray* array, Value value);
```

to another header file (put methods and structures into separate header files).

Comment: Hi, please see my edit adding the code for `value_array.c`.